# Is returning a struct with flexible array member allowed?

Tags: c, arrays, language-lawyer, flexible-array-member

GCC compiles function returning a struct with a flexible array member fine. The Standard gives a definition on how it treats such structs at 6.7.2.1:

> In most situations, the flexible array member is ignored. In
>   particular, the size of the structure is as if the flexible array
>   member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than
>   the omission would imply.

Since the size of the struct with flexible array member is known the type is complete according to the completeness definition given at 6.2.5:

> At various points within a translation unit an object type may be
>   incomplete (lacking sufficient information to determine the size of
>   objects of that type) or complete (having sufficient information). 37)

Also, 6.5.2.2

> The expression that denotes the called function 96) shall have type
>   pointer to function returning void or returning a complete object type
>   other than an array type.

So it should be legal to return `struct`s with flexible array members.

---

How to fix an example below to make it work properly (I need stack allocated struct with flexible array member):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test{
    size_t sz;
    char data[];
};

struct test get_test(void){
    int sz = 5;
    char data[5] = "test";
    struct test test = {.sz = 5};
    //How to copy char data[5] into the struct test test?
    return test;
}

int main(void){
    struct test tst = get_test();
    printf("%s\n", tst.data);
}
```

Comment: You can create such an object but you can't access the flexible array element.

Comment: If you want to access flexible member, don't use automatic variable. Use from the family of `malloc` or [if availble `P99_FMALLOC`](https://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__flexible.html).

Comment: You say: _I need stack allocated struct with flexible array member._  The standard says you can create such a struct but that the size allocated will not include any space for the flexible array member.  Such structures are rarely useful therefore.  You can deal in pointers to such structures — they'll need to be dynamically allocated (using `malloc()` et al) to be useful (non-empty flexible array members).  Compilers are free to provide extensions — and GCC does.  But the 'language lawyer' tag implies you don't care about such extensions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler By using GCC's extensions how can it be done? I mean stack-allocated of a struct with initialized flexible array member.

Comment: Second half of the GCC documentation on C extensions and [Arrays of Length Zero](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Zero-Length.html#Zero-Length).  It isn't remotely clear that you could return a value like that.  If it was statically allocated, you could return a pointer to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is valid C to return such a value, but none of the array elements will be copied. The automatic variable will behave as if it did allocate with an array of length 1 (because array length of 0 is not valid in standard C), but accesses to `.data[0]` will have UB - the actual *size* of the object might include the `.data[0]` and perhaps even more successive elements - or then not.([C11 6.7.2.1p18](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p18)).

It is not possible to define an automatic variable that would have any content in the flexible array member in *standard C* (extensions may and do exist)!

An assignment is valid too (and hence returning too), but again the flexible array member will contain indeterminate values ([C11 6.7.2.1p25](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p25)) after assignment.

Comment: It is problematic to say “The automatic variable will behave as if it did allocate an array length 1.” The C standard has some wording similar to this, in C 2018 6.7.2.1 18, but it is discussing referencing the flexible array member with a `.` or `->` operator, not the behavior of the entire structure or defining one with an automatic object. For example, the size of the automatic object will not be as if the array length were 1.

Comment: (Also, technically, I do not believe “It is not possible to define an automatic variable that would have any content in the flexible array member in standard C” is true. The flexible array member behaves as if replaced with the largest possible array that fits in the object. If the object necessarily has padding, that may provide space for elements. For example, with `struct { double x; char y; char z[]; } t;`, then, in many C implementations, `t.z` behaves as if it had at least 7 elements. Not that I recommend taking advantage of this.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil the standard explicitly says that the elements are indeterminate and access undefined so I wouldn't argue too much about that.

Answer (score 4):

> How to fix an example below to make it work properly (I need stack
>   allocated struct with flexible array member):

A Flexible Array Member allows for a single dynamic allocation of both the struct and FAM. (you can't have a stack allocated struct and dynamic FAM -- if you want to do that, don't use a FAM, use a pointer for `data` instead.) To allocate and utilize the FAM, you need to change your function to return a pointer to type `struct test` (e.g. `struct test*`) and then declare and allocate storage for both your struct and storage for `"test"` in `get_test` and return a pointer to the allocated block, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct test {
    size_t sz;
    char data[];
};

struct test *get_test (void)    /* declare as type struct test* */
{
    size_t sz = 5;
    char data[] = "test";

    /* allocate storage for struct + FAM */
    struct test *test = malloc (sizeof *test + sizeof data);
    if (!test)
        return NULL;

    test->sz = sz;                              /* assign sz */
    memcpy (test->data, data, sizeof data);     /* copy data */

    return test;
}

int main (void) {

    struct test *tst = get_test();

    printf ("test->sz   : %zu\ntest->data : %s\n", tst->sz, tst->data);

    free (tst);     /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fam
test->sz   : 5
test->data : test
```